# Can't play the downloaded .mp3 file

Tags: android, audio, download, mp3, android-download-manager

I'm downloading an .mp3 within an app but I can't play it only on Windows Media Player. I tried it with Microsoft Groove Music Player, Google Play Music a built in Music player on my phone but neither won't open it... just the media player :D
So do you have any ideas what the issue could be?

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(mediaURL));
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfTheFile + "." + extension);

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
```

If I delete the "request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");" line, Media Player can still play it.

Comment: Can you play the audio file when you download it using a web browser?

Comment: Wow, I opened it with Internet Explore, then it added to it's downlods and from there I could open it with Groove

Comment: So if I copy them to the computer I can play them with Groove too

Comment: I downloaded another Audio Player onto my phone and it says that the files is invalid...

Comment: It works but .jpg too.... but with .mp3 not :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was that I had a colon in the filename...